# Postgres distinct on in sqlalchemy join: subquery must return only one column

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a table of posts and a table of comments on those posts. There is no foreign key constraint, but the post_id on a comment refers to the id on a post.

I am using a query like this to get a list of recent posts with the text of the most recent comment on that post:

```
SELECT posts.*, comments.text
FROM posts
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT ON ("post_id") *
    FROM comments
    ORDER BY "post_id", "timestamp" DESC
) comments ON posts.id=comments.post_id
WHERE posts.timestamp >= start_date;
```

I would like to convert this query to use with sqlalchemy expressions. I have tried this:

```
query = select(posts, comments.c.text).\
    join(comments, and_(select(comments).
        distinct(comments.c.post_id).
        order_by(comments.c.post_id, comments.c.timestamp.desc()),
        posts.c.id == comments.c.post_id), isouter=True).\
    where(posts.c.timestamp >= start_date)
```

But it is creating a slightly different query:

```
SELECT posts.id, posts.[other posts columns...], comments.text
FROM posts 
LEFT OUTER JOIN comments ON (
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (comments.post_id) comments.text, comments.[other comments columns...]
    FROM comments 
    ORDER BY comments.post_id, comments.timestamp DESC
) AND posts.id = comments.post_id 
WHERE posts.timestamp >= start_date;
```

which results in an error: `sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError) subquery must return only one column`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
comments_subquery = db.session.query(comments).distinct(comments.post_id, comments.text).subquery()

query = db.session.query(posts, comments.text)\
        .outerjoin(comments_subquery, comments_subquery.c.post_id==posts.id)
        .filter(posts.timestamp >= start_date)
        .all()
```